# How to print int and char together from 2d array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What I want to get is 4x4 matrix or larger and replace integers of center to characters.
such as

```
 1   2   3   4
 5   6   7   8
 9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

fill out numbers not by manual writing. It can be 8X8 10X10 matrix

```
 1   2   3   4 
 5   A   B   8
 9   B   B  12
13  14  15  16
```

```
void (int arr[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE],int nrow){

    for (int row = 0; row < nrow; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < nrow; col++)
        {
            arr[row][col] = i++;
            if (nrow / 2 == row && nrow / 2 == col)
            {
                arr[row - 1][col - 1] = 'A';
                arr[row - 1][col] = 'B';
                arr[row][col - 1] = 'B';
                arr[row][col] = 'A';
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int row = 0; row < nrow; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < nrow; col++)
        {
            cout<< arr[row][col];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I tried to make it char by

```
char charArray[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]=arr[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

But It shows weird characters and if I do

```
charArray[row][col] =i +'0';
```

It shows me numbers before 10 and over 10 would be the same weird charaters.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Forgot to mention but  void(int arr[MAX SIZE][MAX Size],int nrow) never should be changed

Comment: `void(int arr[MAX SIZE][MAX Size],int nrow)` **must be changed** in C (don't know about C++). It's a syntax violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code and let me know if you have any qeustions.

```
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 8; // You can change this to create larger matrices

void fillMatrix(char arr[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE], int nrow) {
    char ch = 'A';
    int center = nrow / 2;

    for (int row = 0; row < nrow; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < nrow; col++) {
            if (row == center && col == center) {
                arr[row][col] = ch++;
            } else {
                arr[row][col] = ch;
            }
            ch++; // Move to the next character
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char charArray[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

    fillMatrix(charArray, MAX_ARRAY_SIZE);

    for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; col++) {
            std::cout << charArray[row][col] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                                                                                                      #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
int arr[6]={'A','B',1,3,4,5};
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
if(arr[i]>0&&arr[i]<9)
cout<<arr[i]<<"\n";
else
{
printf("%c\n",arr[i]);
}


}
return 0;
}
```

> This will help you.